# db.Model vs db.Table in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The [Flask-SQLAlchemy docs](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#many-to-many-relationships) say that many-to-many lookup tables should not subclass db.Model but instead be written as db.Tables. From the docs:

> If you want to use many-to-many relationships you will need to define
>   a helper table that is used for the relationship. For this helper
>   table it is strongly recommended to not use a model but an actual
>   table

Why? What are the downsides to making everything a model? I think it looks cleaner to have a unified way of declaring tables in the database. Also, it's possible that sometime later a developer will want to access those mapping records directly, rather than through a relationship, which would require a model.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**The `db.Table` is more simple.**

When you define a many-to-many relationship through `db.Table`, SQLAlchemy would take over and do most of the job for you.

So, assuming that we have a relationship with posts and tags with the following `Table` and `Model` definitions:

Table:

```
tagging = db.Table('tagging',
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
)
```

Model:

```
class Tagging(db.Model):
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'),
                              primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'),
                               primary_key=True)
```

### Insert and delete

As the description in [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#deleting-rows-from-the-many-to-many-table):

> A behavior which is unique to the secondary argument to relationship() is that **the Table which is specified here is automatically subject to INSERT and DELETE statements, as objects are added or removed from the collection**. There is no need to delete from this table manually. The act of removing a record from the collection will have the effect of the row being deleted on flush.

With `db.Table`, you can do something like this:

```
>>> post.tags.append(tag_foo)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

You needn't add it into session, then you can delete a relationship with `remove()`:

```
>>> post.tags.remove(tag_foo)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

However, if you use `db.Model`, you have to do something like this (`Tagging` is the Model class):

```
>>> tagging = Tagging(post=post_foo, tag=tag_bar)
>>> db.session.add(tagging)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

then delete it like this:

```
>>> tagging = post.tags.filter_by(post_id=post.id).first()
>>> db.session.delete(tagging)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

### Query

With `db.Table`:

```
>>> post.tags.all()
>>> [<Tag 'foo'>, ...]
```

Then `db.Model`:

```
>>> post.tags.all()  # You only get Tagging item.
>>> [<Tagging 'post_foo -- tag_bar'>, ...]
>>> for tagging in post.tags:
>>>     print tagging.tag  # <Tag 'foo'>
```

In a word, if you don't need to store extra data about the relationship, just use `db.Table`, it will save your time.

Comment: What if you DO need to store extra data about the relationship?

Comment: Then use `db.Model`.

Comment: If `db.Model` already exists for a table in my app, is there any use case that justifies *also* creating a `db.Table` for the same table? I'm maintaining old code and it looks like the previous guy did both...