# SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship updating association object with extra column

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

In my application, a '**set**' can have a number of '**products**' associated with it. Products listed against a set must have quantities defined. For this many-to-many relationship I have followed the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) to use an association table with an additional column (quantity).

I am trying to create a form where the user can assign products and quantities against a given set. Both the sets and products already exist in the database. The data from the form are:

- set.id
- product.id
- quantity

This works to create a new association (e.g. set 1 is 'linked' to product 3 with quantity=XYZ) but I get an integrity error when I try to update an existing record.

I can manually add a relationship/record (dummy data) or within the Flask view function as follows:

```
s = Set.query.get(2)
p = Product.query.get(3)
a = Set_Product_Association(set=s, product=p, quantity=23)
db.session.add(a)
db.session.commit()
```

Updating the record (different quantity) manually as follows works:

```
s.products[0].quantity = 43
db.session.add(s)
db.session.commit()
```

However when I use the code from the first block instead (with the aim to update the `quantity` field for a given, existing set and product ID), i.e.:

```
a = Set_Product_Association(set=s, product=p, quantity=43)
```

I get an integrity error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: set_product_association.set_id, set_product_association.product_id [SQL: 'INSERT INTO set_product_association (set_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (2, 3, 43)]
```

I assume this is to tell me that I'm trying to append a new record rather than updating the existing one.

How should I approach this? The 'manual' method works but relies on working out the correct index in the list (i.e. for the correct product.id).

Curiously, if I use `form.popluate_obj(set)` in my Flask view function to process the form data as described in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319689/using-wtforms-populate-obj-to-update-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-c), I can update fields but not create new 'associations'. Unfortunately, I don't know what goes on behind the scenes there....

My models are defined like so:

```
class Set_Product_Association(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'set_product_association'

    set_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sets.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)

    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)

    product = db.relationship("Product", back_populates="sets")
    set = db.relationship("Set", back_populates="products")

class Set(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sets'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = db.relationship("Set_Product_Association", 
                                        back_populates="set")

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    part_number = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    sets = db.relationship("Set_Product_Association", 
                                     back_populates="product")
```

**Edit:**
I've also tried reversing the operation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188660/integrityerror-when-inserting-data-in-an-association-table-using-sqlalchemy):

```
s = Set.query.get(2)
a = Set_Product_Association()
a.quantity = 43
a.product = Product.query.get(3)
a.set = s
db.session.commit()
```

But I still get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: set_product_association.set_id, set_product_association.product_id [SQL: 'INSERT INTO set_product_association (set_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (2, 3, 43)]
```

Comment: `a = Set_Product_Association(set_id=3, product_id=12, quantity=23)`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but as you can see in the error I referenced, it has got the correct values, so your suggestion doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an integrity error because you are trying to create a new object with the same primary keys.

This:

```
a = Set_Product_Association(set=s, product=p, quantity=43)
```

Does not update, but create.

If you want to update the actual row in the table, you need to update the existing one:

```
assoc = Set_Product_Association.query.filter_by(set=s, product=p).first()
assoc.quantity = 43
db.session.commit()
```

Also, from the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) it is advised to not use a model but an actual table.

Comment: Thank very much for your help and explanation - much appreciated! Works & makes perfect sense. Regarding using an actual table over a model, for my use case here, where would you suggest recording the extra information (quantity) if I wanted to follow that advice?

Comment: Keep the same structure (set, product and quantity), but using the `db.Table` method rather than extending `db.Model`.

A good answer to why it is better can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047925/1232796), with examples.

Comment: Thanks. It's clearly obvious that I'm new to this so apologies if I'm being slow to follow. The reason why I went with a model over a table is that I need to store additional information about the relationship. The info you linked states that "In a word, if you don't need to store extra data about the relationship, just use `db.Table`, it will save your time." So my problem is that I **do** want to store extra data...

Comment: Keep the model then, it doesn't matter.